# How to get a list contacts that have not donated within a certain amount of time?

Tags: civicontribute, contacts, civireport, contributions

Hello CiviCRM community,

I've been trying to wrap my head around this and can't seem to figure it out.

I'm looking to get list of contacts that have not donated within a certain amount of time to target them to donate.

Any ideas on how to run this report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the CiviRules extension to achieve this. With this extension you can check if contacts in a certain group have not donated for a period of time for example.

You can find the extension here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules (or in your extension list)

Documentation on using this extension can be found here:https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) extension to get that is required. You can setup triggers, conditions and actions using this extension.

A detailed documentation has been compiled by them which can be found [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/).

Hope this helps.